# PHP connection with SQL server error, activating 3 buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I having trouble with connecting to my database (in phpMyAdmin), and activating three buttons. My database is **medecin**, my table is **client**, Ii want to activate the **insert** , **modify client**, and **deleting** bottons. Here's the interface code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Client</legend>
    <table border="1">
        <form method=post action="client.php">
            <tr>
                <td> Id : </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="id_client" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Nom : </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="nom" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Preom : </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="prenom" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Age : </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="age" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Tel : </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="tel"  /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> eMail : </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="mail" /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="insert" name="Ajouter Client" /> <br> <br>  
        <input type="submit" value="Modify Client" /> <br> <br>  
        <input type="submit" value="delete Client" /> <br> <br> <br>
    </form>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

My PHP code (`client.php`) to activate the buttons:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'medecin';
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);
//Connect to MySQL and instantiate our PDO object.
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $pass, $options);
$id_client=$_POST['id_client'];
$nom=$_POST['nom'];
$prenom=$_POST['prenom'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
$mail=$_POST['mail'];
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    //activating insert button
    $sql ="INSERT INTO client VALUES (id_client=? ,nom=? ,prenom=?, age=?, tel=? , mail=?)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(1, $id_client);
    $statement->bindValue(2, $nom);
    $statement->bindValue(3, $prenom);
    $statement->bindValue(4, $age);
    $statement->bindValue(5, $tel);
    $statement->bindValue(6, $mail);
    $statement->execute();
    $inserted = $statement->execute();
    if ($inserted) {
        echo 'Row inserted!<br>';
    }       
} elseif (isset($_POST['supprimer Client'])) {
    $sql = 'DELETE from client WHERE id_client= :id_client ';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':id_client', $id_client);
    $delete = $statement->execute();
} elseif (isset($_POST['Modifier Client'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE medecin SET id_client=?, nom=?, prenom=?, age=?, tel=?, mail=? WHERE id_client=?";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':id_client', $id_client);
    $statement->bindValue(':nom', $nom);
    $statement->bindValue(':prenom', $prenom);
    $statement->bindValue(':age', $age);
    $statement->bindValue(':tel', $tel);
    $statement->bindParam(':mail', $mail);
    $statement->execute()
}
?>
```

I can't figure what I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect using something like this and put this in another `php` file and when you want to use it use `include(PHP file name)` or `include_once(PHP file name)`.

```
try{
        $dbConnect = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass);
        $dbConnect -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo "ERROR: ".$ex->getMessage();
        exit();
}
```

I kind of fixed your `PHP` code as well there were some errors.

```
<?php
include_once ('dbconnect.php');

if (isset($_POST['insert']))
//activating insert button
{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO client VALUES (id_client=:id_client ,nom=:nom ,prenom=:prenom, age=:age, tel=:tel , mail=:mail)");
    $statement->bindParam(':id_client', $id_client);
    $statement->bindParam(':nom', $nom);
    $statement->bindParam(':prenom', $prenom);
    $statement->bindParam(':age', $age);
    $statement->bindParam(':tel', $tel);
    $statement->bindParam(':mail', $mail);
 if($statement->execute();){
    echo 'Row inserted!<br>';}      
}
    elseif (isset($_POST['supprimer Client'])) {        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("DELETE from client WHERE id_client= :id_client");
        $statement->bindParam(':id_client', $id_client);
        $statement->execute();
}
elseif (isset($_POST['Modifier Client'])) {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE medecin SET id_client=:id_client ,nom=:nom ,prenom=:prenom, age=:age, tel=:tel , mail=:mail WHERE id_client=:id_client");
        $statement->bindParam(':id_client', $id_client);
        $statement->bindParam(':nom', $nom);
        $statement->bindParam(':prenom', $prenom);
        $statement->bindParam(':age', $age);
        $statement->bindParam(':tel', $tel);
        $statement->bindParam(':mail', $mail);
        $statement->execute()
        }
?>
```